# IE8 .attachEvent() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I was using this bit of jQuery in order to enable a button on my page to toggle a div.

```
var SnapEnable = document.getElementById('open-right');
$(SnapEnable).addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (snapper.state().state == "right") {
        snapper.close();
    }
    else {
        snapper.open('right');
    }
});
```

I was getting an error In IE8 with this bit of code "Object doesn't support this property or method". So I updated my code to below:
    var SnapEnable = document.getElementById('open-right');

```
if (!SnapEnable.addEventListener) {
    $(SnapEnable).attachEvent("onclick", function() {
    if (snapper.state().state == "right") {
        snapper.close();
    }
    else {
        snapper.open('right');
        }
    });
}
else {
    $(SnapEnable).addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (snapper.state().state == "right") {
        snapper.close();
    }
    else {
        snapper.open('right');
        }
});
};
```

I thought this would fix the issue but I am still getting the error.

Comment: if you are using jQuery then why not using `.on()` to bind click event? and yes you don't have to check for ie and others.

Comment: This works in *non-IE* browsers? I would be surprised if it did.. (jQuery doesn't define an `addEventListener`, so it'll fail in the "else" case as well; the ridiculous checking is to deal with cross-browser compatibility issues, which jQuery already handles *sigh*)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I need to go back to the beginning and learn the basics of jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow...
Try to read the documentation of jQuery (you mix jQuery and pure js instructions)...

(fixed)

Try this:

```
$('#open-right').click(function(e) {
    if (snapper.state().state == "right") {
        snapper.close();
    }
    else {
        snapper.open('right');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I most certainly do need to read up on jQuery!

Answer (score 5):

You're checking the existance of `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener`, then using `$` which converts it to a *jQuery Object* which doesn't support that interface.

It's the difference between `SnapEnable` and `$(SnapEnable)`.

If you're using *jQuery*, you probably want [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You are totally right, I was staring at my code for ages and didn't even notice that. Sometimes in needs a fresh set of eyes! Thank you.